# Code showing error *** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c++

This code is not running properly and showing the following error at runtime:

> stack smashing detected: ./a.out terminated
>   Aborted (core dumped)

However, if we declare temp with i, j it works. The error is also shown if we declare temp in the if block.  The error is not shown if we declare the array size explicitly. I am compiling my code with the GNU compiler.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int a[] = {3, 2, 4, 1};
    int temp;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 4 - i; j++)
        {
            if(a[j] > a[j + 1])
            {
                int temp;
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }

    return 2;
}
```

Comment: When `j` is 3, you access `a[j+1]` which is `a[4]` which is past the boundary of the array.

Comment: Buffer overrun with `a[j + 1]` when `j == 3`.

Comment: One of you needs to add this an answer, not a comment.

Comment: It's probably a duplicate of either an existing stack smash or buffer overrun question, tbh

Comment: I can't be bothered with spending time on dup seaches for debugging fails like this one.   I just DCV for Off-Topic/Questions seeking debugging help...  I don't want rep off stuff like this.

Answer (score 7):

Your code accesses `a[j+1]`. When `j` is 4, this attempts to access `a[4]`, which is out of bounds; size of `a` is 4, so the last element is `a[3]`.

Accessing array index that is out of bounds is undefined behavior. It may work, or it may not.

You say when you write this, your program does not crash:

```
int a[]={3,2,4,1};
int temp;
```

This happens, because your program reserves memory for `a`, and it places `temp` in the memory right after that. So when you try to change value of `a[4]`, you actually change value of `temp`.

When you remove `int temp;`, it seems your program places no other variables to the memory location that would correspond `a[4]`. It crashes because it has no access to that memory location.